# Is there a way I could get past the first UFO part in Eternelle Vehemence by Vrymer more consistently in Geometry Dash?

Tags: geometry-dash, mobile

---

#### Background

---

So, after taking a brief hiatus from playing Geometry Dash and experimenting a bit with different hard demons that I might want to beat for my second hard demon (for anyone who wants to know, my first hard demon ever was Nine Circles), I decided to start trying to beat [Eternelle Vehemence](https://geometry-dash-fan.fandom.com/wiki/Eternelle_Vehemence) by Vrymer. So, I began playing it, and after 42 and a half minutes, I got 26% on it.<sup>{1}</sup> After that, I did some runs from 17%, 36%, and 50%, with my best runs being 17-40%, 36-53%, and 50-64%<sup>{2}</sup>

Now, my main problem is: I feel like the place I struggle the most is the first UFO part, and here's why:

1. The blind jump right away at 8% (after you first enter the UFO portal). This could be because I was pausing at 8% to make sure the song was still in sync during the UFO part, but I am unsure if that is the case or not.<sup>{3}</sup>
2. The spikes are for some reason diagonal. This in my opinion honestly makes it harder for me to time my jumps correctly.
3. When I get to the 1x speed portal, I honestly feel like the jumps suddenly become more precise, so it can be hard to predict where I'm going sometimes. Despite this, the 2x UFO part isn't as bad as it seems, since the only problems are the saws, which I honestly think that I have a decent amount of practice navigating the UFO between saws, so it isn't too difficult for me.
4. This *one* jump at 14% (screenshot taken from my 100th attempt on this level):

> [image]

<sub>If you're confused what the colors are supposed to represent, the red circle represents where the jump marker that is hidden behind my trail is, and the green line represents the path that my UFO takes after I jump. Also, if you're confused about where I am in the level, I'm at 14% in this screenshot.</sub>

Now, the main problem with this jump is the fact that no matter *how I jump at that spot*, I always seem to be extremely close to dying there because I always seem to land just to the left of the next jump marker, making it harder to time my following jumps. It's always just heart-racing getting to that point specifically because I know I could fail at that point, and then I'd have to start all over again.

---

### My question

---

Is there a way I can get past the first UFO part in Eternelle Vehemence more consistently? While the 2x speed part doesn't seem to bother me at all, I feel like the 0.5x speed and 1x speed part in the first UFO are just extremely annoying in terms of how consistently I can get past it.

---

#### Notes

---

[<sup>{1}</sup>](https://youtu.be/bIqYcK4l3Tw?si=70ZwuJazOjqMQ6S4)

<sup>{2}</sup>[Runs from 17%](https://youtu.be/EsluMTmpQOU?si=bjGVEH_Tz-yS9JSb), [Runs from 36%](https://youtu.be/ZrJdWNfdkPc?si=hMm_XelwydXYu0Jx), [Runs from 50%](https://youtu.be/NoMA2FIN4c8?si=SQl4F7VUCnAsBKNB)

<sup>{3}</sup>Could be because I play on 60hz or because I play on an iPhone 12 Pro, but idk if that's the problem or not. I also pause at 17% and 23% because of this problem.

Comment: Yes, you can ask these types of questions on Arqade. For things like how to pass something (i.e. levels, passageways, etc) are the intended types of questions.

Comment: @TimMcYeah Oh okay, thanks for clarifying

Comment: You know, I kind of find it unironic how someone who likes mathematics also likes Geometry Dash...

Comment: @TimMcYeah Lol yeah, using the editor in GD requires a lot of math, although it mostly is just basic physics/trigonometry.

Comment: Agreed. I don't play GD a whole lot, but is fun to play from time to time. I'm just a Minecraft nerd lol.